# What the traceback says "self.make_response(rv)" and other?

Tags: flask, server, openai-api

I want to make server for using g4f and openai but:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1487, in full_dispatch_request return self.finalize_request(rv) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1506, in finalize_request response = self.make_response(rv) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1801, in make_response raise TypeError( TypeError: The view function for 'chat_completion' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.`

My file server.py:
`from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import openai
import g4f

app = Flask(**name**)

openai.api_key = ""

message_history = []

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def chat_completion():
global message_history
data = request.json
input_text = data.get('input_text', '')
input_model = data.get('input_model', 'gpt-3.5-turbo')
input_provider = data.get('input_provider', 'openai')

```
message_history.append(input_text)

message_history = message_history[-10:]

prompt = '\n'.join(message_history)

try:
    response = g4f.ChatCompletion.create(model=input_model, provider=input_provider, messages=message_history)

    completion_message = response

    return jsonify({'message': completion_message}), 200

except Exception as e:
    print('')
    # return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500
```

if **name** == '**main**':
app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=1337)
`

I am try editing code but not work.